# Wordpress site member verification emails going to spam on Outlook

Tags: email, spam, email-verification

I am stuck on this for a few days and hope you can help me out:

**Background**

I have a Wordpress site where people can sign up to become members. When they do, they will receive a verification email to be able to access their account, it is the normal Wordpress member sign up form that is used, with PremiumPress as template. The email has the following structure:

> Title: SiteName - Verify your email
>
> Text:
>
> Hi,
>
> Please verify account by the following link:
>
> [www.sitename.ax/verifyuser/userID](http://www.sitename.ax/verifyuser/userID)
>
> Regards,
>
> SiteName
>
> [www.sitename.ax](http://www.sitename.ax), info@sitename.ax

**Problem**

The verification email goes to the spawm folder in Outlook. On Gmail it seems to go into the correct inbox (sometimes into the Promotions folder though).

**What I want**

Verification emails (and all other emails sent from my site) should on all email providers go the the inbox and not the spam folder.

**Research/Questions**

I tested the email through [www.mail-tester.com](http://www.mail-tester.com) and got a score of 8.6/10. Apparently the email isn't signed with DKIM which brings score down with 1, From and EnvelopeFrom 2nd level mail domains are different which is -0.3, and Message only has text/html MIME parts You should also include a text version of your message (text/plain) which is -0.1.

I have no clue how to sign with DKIM, is it my hosting providor that needs to make these changes or can I do it myself in Wordpress?
Are there any other things I can do to prevent it from going to spam folder?

Comment: As this is a question about email service providers/configuration rather than WordPress or it's APIs, it may be considered off-topic on this stack.

Comment: @bosco, you might be right, it should be something commonly experienced when developing Wordpress sites so that is why I asked here. I will try at some other place, thanks!